# How to make a transparent text ignore its parent div background-color?

Tags: html, css, containers, background-color

I have a container div with a background color, a "button" div inside the container -with a different background color- and a text inside the "button" div.

My question is: is it possible to make the text "inherit" the container color, even if the text isn't the container's child?

Only possible solutions without having to resort to JS please.

CSS:

```
.container{
  background-color: red;
}

.button{
background-color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
   <a href="#">THE TEXT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The given CSS and HTML are just an example to my real problem, which contains a lot of "buttons" and "containers".

Comment: use CSS variable to define the color?

Comment: @isherwood I did that. But as I have many divs, with different background colors it would create too many variables for each buttons in each container. My objective is to make my CSS cleaner with a possible single -or as close to it- change.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to define a CSS variable in the container and use this to set both the container background color and the anchor element's text color.

This works because in a sense a child will 'inherit' the setting of a CSS variable (property).

```css
.container {
  --color: red;
  background-color: var(--color);
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
}

.button a {
  color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">
    <a href="#">THE TEXT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note, in this snippet the container has been given some styling so we can see it.